# trying to remove everything above a certain line

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Say I have the following string:

```
$str = 'Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 28 B5 8E 16 11 88 E9 00 58 D5 76 30 12 B9 59 B8 E4 CE 7C AA
subject=/C=UK/ST=Suffolk/L=Ipswich/O=Example plc/CN=alice
issuer=/C=UK/ST=Suffolk/L=Ipswich/O=Example plc/CN=Certificate Authority/emailAddress=ca@example.com
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDDzCCAfegAwIBAgIJAMkyzQVK88NHMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGCMQswCQYD
VQQGEwJTRTESMBAGA1UECBMJU3RvY2tob2xtMQ4wDAYDVQQHEwVLaXN0YTEQMA4G
[...]
0fbkqbKulrchGbNgkankZtEVg4PGjo+Y8MdMjtfSZB29hwYvfMX09jzJ68ZqmpYQ
njvcVtLbEZN5OGCkaslb/f2OxLbsUNgIbws538WnaaufDvKmQe2kUdWmpl9Wn9Bf
bZq7B+njvcVa7SsWF/WLq5AUbw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----';
```

I want to remove everything above (and potentially including) the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` however I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. Note that it isn't always going to be `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`. It could be `--BEGIN CERTIFICATE--` (with two -'s on either side) or it could be `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` or stuff like that.

Anyway here's what I've tried:

1. `echo preg_replace('#.*?-+[^\r\n]-+#s', '', $str);`

   `-+[^\r\n]-+` matches `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` so with the above I'm trying to match every character up to that with the .*? but it isn't working. It's stopping at the `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` not at the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`.
2. `echo preg_replace('#.*?-+[^\r\n]-+#s', '', $str);`

   Same thing as before. Even though the ?, in this case, is supposed to be changing the greedy-ness, it doesn't in fact seem to actually be doing anything.

   ie. I'm trying to match every character up to
3. `echo preg_replace('#[.\r\n]*?-+.+-+#', '', $str);`

   Here I'm trying to match every character up to and including `-+.+-+`. I can do `.` instead of `[^\r\n]` since I'm not using the s modifier but it isn't working here either. Instead it's just matching the `-+.+-+` part as though the `[.\r\n]*?` doesn't exit.

Any ideas?

Comment: So ? And why don't you just use `explode()` ?

Comment: why not `strstr($text, '------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----')`? Using a regex for a simple string operation is like nuking a building to swat a fly in one of the closets.

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV - because I don't want to convert the string to an array? Because I'd rather have succinct code instead of having to do a for loop etc? Because I want to further my understanding of regex?

Comment: @Marc B - what if it's not `------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` but is instead `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`? Or what if it's `--BEGIN CERTIFICATE--` with only two dashes on either side instead of five? That's why I'm using regular expressions.

Comment: Then mention that in your question. It's not our job to assume that you want a generalized solution for all certificate types.

Comment: @dnagirl: this isn't an email header and has nothing to do with email.

Comment: Seems that some things should go without saying. If I ask why `echo str_repeat(2, '-')` isn't outputting `--` the correct answer isn't "why aren't you doing `echo '--';`?" - it's that I should be `str_repeat('-', 2)`. Never the less I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$str = 'Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 28 B5 8E 16 11 88 E9 00 58 D5 76 30 12 B9 59 B8 E4 CE 7C AA
subject=/C=UK/ST=Suffolk/L=Ipswich/O=Example plc/CN=alice
issuer=/C=UK/ST=Suffolk/L=Ipswich/O=Example plc/CN=Certificate Authority/emailAddress=ca@example.com
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDDzCCAfegAwIBAgIJAMkyzQVK88NHMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGCMQswCQYD
VQQGEwJTRTESMBAGA1UECBMJU3RvY2tob2xtMQ4wDAYDVQQHEwVLaXN0YTEQMA4G
[...]
0fbkqbKulrchGbNgkankZtEVg4PGjo+Y8MdMjtfSZB29hwYvfMX09jzJ68ZqmpYQ
njvcVtLbEZN5OGCkaslb/f2OxLbsUNgIbws538WnaaufDvKmQe2kUdWmpl9Wn9Bf
bZq7B+njvcVa7SsWF/WLq5AUbw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----';

preg_match('/(?P<begin>-+[^-]+-+)(?P<body>.*?)(?P<end>-+[^-]+-+)/s', $str, $m);

echo 'begin: '. $m['begin'] .'<br>body: '.$m['body'].'<br> end: '. $m['end'];
```

Some explanation:

**(?P`<begin>`** => Start named group

**-+** => Match one of "-" or more

**[^-]+** => Match every character until "-" is found

**-+** => Match one of "-" or more

**)** => Closing group

**/s** => The s modifier is set, so a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, **including newlines**

---

Here's a preg_replace() solution:

`$str = preg_replace('/.*?(-+[^-]+-+.*?-+[^-]+-+)/s', '$1', $str);`

Comment: Hmmm - that'd do it. I was so stuck on using preg_replace that I didn't think about using preg_match lol. Am still curious as to why preg_replace isn't working though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pre = ';.*-+BEGIN CERTIFICATE-+';
$post = '-+END CERTIFICATE-+';
$out = preg_replace('/' . $pre . '(.*)' . $post . '/is', "$1", $str);
```

You may want to preserve your original string ...

Comment: You'd have to use the s modifier to make it work with new lines. And do keep in mind to that I want it to match more than just `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`. Heck - replace that with `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` so that there were two of those and then your regex would break. It'd match not the first one but the last one and replace everything.